# Vim - highlight c# regions

Tags: vim, highlight, region

is there a way to highlight c# regions in vim.

Similar to this:

[image]

Just some way to make it easier to spot regions in files.
(By the way I am using OmniSharp for c# completion in vim)

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are requesting, but you can do the following:

```
:syntax region csregion start=/#region/ end=/#endregion/
:highlight csregion guibg=Yellow
```

or otherwise use folding:

```
:setlocal foldmethod=syntax
```

then `zc` to close the fold where the cursor is in, `zo` to open it, `zM` to close all folds, `zR` to open all folds, etc.